# Wrong timing for comment editing blocking?

Tags: bug, comment, editing, timestamps

I just wanted to edit a comment of mine that was shown as "3 min ago". When I hit the button to commit the edit, I was told that editing is only possible for 5 minutes. OK, so I took too long to edit? But when I hit cancel, it showed only "4 min ago". I tried again, and only after having no success again and cancelling again, I got "5 min ago". Is there something wrong about the 5 minute time limit versus the displayed age of comment? Even taking rounding issues into consideration, the "4 min ago" after (forced) cancelling seems to indicate that something is wrong (or unexpectedly offset).

Answer (score 6):

The timestamp that is automatically updated is calculated in Javascript on your computer. If your computer now has a wrong date and time set, the calculated timestamp will be wrong.

From your description is sounds like the time on your computer is a few minutes wrong.

Comment: Answer to this meta.SO question confirms that the taime on the local machine is used: [Timewarp in the comment time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164845/timewarp-in-the-comment-time).